# Filter and sort a List

Tags: python, list, sorting, filter

Filter and sort a list
Write a program that gets a list of integers from input, and outputs non-negative integers in ascending order (lowest to highest).

Ex: If the input is:

```
10 -7 4 39 -6 12 2
```

the output is:

```
2 4 10 12 39
```

For coding simplicity, follow every output value by a space. Do not end with newline.

I have tried and come up with a TypeError on line 7. I have tried everything to fix it. A hint or help would be appreciated. Been at it for hours trying to figure out how to fix the error, so zybooks accepts the answer.

This is my code.

```
# asking for user input

       nums = input()

        lst = nums.split() # user input splits
# starting of a new list
new_list = ([])
for i in lst:  # for loop to see if i in lst is true
    if int(i) > 0: # if loop to see it integer is greater than 0  <--- This is where my error is
    
new_list.append(int(i)) # adding integers to the end
new_list.sort() # sorting new list in order, lowest to largest
for x in new_list: # seeing if x is true in the new list
   print(x, end=' ') # printing new list in new order
```

The Error I am receiving is:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    if int(i) > 0: # if loop to see it integer is greater than 0 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10,'
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: This is the error I'm getting. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    if int(i) > 0: # if loop to see it integer is greater than 0 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10,'

Comment: Also, first time posting on here. Sorry about the indentations. It's not the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean: `lst = nums.split(',')`? Or do you mean for the user to enter space delimited numbers?

Comment: if int(i) > 0:    that's the part of the code giving me trouble

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: I can see from your error traceback that your input seems to have commas in it. Do you expect your user to enter something like: `10, 11, 12` or `10 11 12`?

Comment: I expect the users input to come back in order, lowest to highest. no negatives

Comment: What is the actual input you are using?

Answer (score 2):

You are facing indentation errors most probably. I have edited your code to the proper indentation try this -

```
nums = input()
lst = nums.split()

new_list = []

for i in lst:  # for loop to see if i in lst is true
    if int(i) > 0:
        new_list.append(int(i)) # adding integers to the end

new_list.sort() # sorting new list in order, lowest to largest

for x in new_list: # seeing if x is true in the new list
    print(x, end=' ') # printing new list in new order
```

```
10 -7 4 39 -6 12 2

2 4 10 12 39
```

---

Here is a cleaner way to do this with a one-liner [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp).

```
out = sorted([int(i) for i in input().split() if int(i)>0])
print(out)
```

```
10 -7 4 39 -6 12 2

[2, 4, 10, 12, 39]
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentation problems aside, you can consider using list comprehensions to solve the problem in a more Pythonic way :)

```
def filter_and_sort(nums):
  """Returns a sorted 'list' of `nums`, only considering any `num > 0`."""
  return sorted(num for num in nums if num > 0)

# read user input, `strip()` whitespace and `split()` on space,
# and cast each entry to an int
input_numbers = map(int, input().strip().split())

sorted_numbers = filter_and_sort(input_numbers)

# map each number into a string, then join strings using a space, and print to screen.
print(" ".join(map(str, sorted_numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nums = input()

list = nums.split()

new_list = []

for i in list:

    if int(i) >= 0:
        new_list.append(int(i)) 

new_list.sort() 

for x in new_list:
 
    print(x, end=' ')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In particular, don't just post a code blob, but explain why the code answers the question.